# Wygwam not loading tool bar

Tags: wygwam

All of a sudden wigwam stopped loading the tool bar. I can not click in the field, either to publish or edit, there is no field, no tool bar. Its been working great for 3 months. I am running EE 2.6.1 and wigwam 3.2.1.

I checked the Editor Configurations and they are fine, nothing has changed. I checked he field type and it set to Wigwam. In edit mode, if I change the field type to Textarea, the content is there as with HTML tags (like source mode). The content is still their I can see it on the website, and it formatted. Look great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this probably points to javascript errors. check with devtools or firebug what is going on.